# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: (Python: I am having this error even though the file does exist)

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, compiler-errors

in the error output message I have the .json file in a streamed tweets folder. The data exists im not sure what is wrong with my path

```
import json
import os, os.path

# counter keeps track of the unique tweet ids and is used later when 
#  prepending the ElasticSearch compatibility
counter = 1

# find all files in folderPath, does not include subdirectories or directories
folderPath = r"c:/Users/Katherine/Downloads/Final Project-.zip/Final
    Project/122_finalproject_part2/streamed_tweets";
files = next(os.walk(folderPath))[2]
# filecount is keeps track of how many files are in the streamedtweets folder
filecount = len(files) - 1
print(filecount)

ctr = 0
for ctr in range(filecount):
    inFileName = open('streamedtweets/tweet_data_' + str(filecount)  + '.json', 'r')
    outFileName = open('elastic_data/elastictwitter_data_' + str(filecount) + '.json', 'w')

ERROR
 File "add_elastic.py", line 16, in <module>
    inFileName = open('streamedtweets/tweet_data_' + str(filecount)  + '.json', 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'streamedtweets/tweet_data_32.json'
```

Comment: This does not solve your question but, should not it be `str(ctr)`  instead of `str(filecount)`?

Comment: Your python file might not be working in the directory you think.  Check the output of print(os. getcwd()), if it does not say "c:/Users/Katherine/Downloads/Final Project-.zip/Final Project/122_finalproject_part2/"  then you are looking for your files in the wrong place

Comment: @Hoog I checked it is the same. Any other advice?

Comment: @kit I think @MiguelIsla's comment actually is your solution.  You expected `tweet_data_` to be appended with `0, 1, 2, 3`... but in actuality you're always appending `32` which doesn't seem to exist.  A better way would be to loop directly through the files you have instead of guessing its name.

Answer (score 0):

You expected `tweet_data_` to be appended with `0, 1, 2, 3`... but in actuality you're always appending `32` which doesn't seem to exist. A better way would be to loop directly through the files you have instead of guessing its name.

Try doing this instead:

```
folderPath = r"c:/Users/Katherine/Downloads/Final Project-.zip/Final
    Project/122_finalproject_part2/streamed_tweets"
files = next(os.walk(folderPath))[2]

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    if file.startswith('tweet_data_') and file.endswith('.json'):
        inFileName = open(file, 'r')
        outFileName = open('elastic_data/elastictwitter_data_' + str(i) + '.json', 'w')
```

And even better way would be to use the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to manage your files opening and closing:

```
for i, file in enumerate(files):
    if file.startswith('tweet_data_') and file.endswith('.json'):
        with open(file, 'r') as inFileName, open('elastic_data/elastictwitter_data_' + str(i) + '.json', 'w') as outFileName:
            # do something with inFileName / outFileName
```